# Batch script make setlocal variable accessed by other batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am writing a batch file to read a path from file and set it to environment variable. This batch file will be used (called) by many other batch files to get the variable. While writing the batch file I faced a problem will variable expansion so I used `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to overcome this issue. But doing so the other batch files which is using it are not able to get the variables set.

Below is the batch script,

```
getVariables.bat

@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (test.dat) do set %%I
    echo setting JAVA_HOME to :: !JAVA_HOME!
    echo setting JAVA to !JAVA!
)
```

In my another batch file I am using the above batach file to get the variables set

```
   another.bat
 
   call getVariables.dat
   echo "%JAVA%"
```

But echo is printing "", where it is not set. If this is because of `setlocal`, how can I overcome this ? I also need `setlocal` for delaying the expansion and to occur at execution time. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 26):

To set multiple global variables to the value of local variables, use the following trick:

```
endlocal & (
  set "globalvar1=%localvar1%"
  set "globalvar2=%localvar2%"
  set "globalvar3=%localvar3%"
)
```

The variables in the ( ) block are expanded before endlocal is executed.

Comment: You can actually set a variable to its own name, e.g., `endlocal & set var=%var%`. The `endlocal` destroys the variable, but its value has already been substituted, so the `set` command immediately recreates it.

Answer (score 6):

This `endlocal & set str=value`will work wonders.

Comment: That was the problem with me.  I am in the habit of using SETLOCAL in all my scripts.   Finally, I found one exception where it caused a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on quite what you're doing - and whether you've posted the full script.

First, you have unbalanced `%` in `%test.dat`

Next, it's a good idea to name batch files `.bat` not `.dat`

Next, if the only purpose of this `getVariables.bat` is to set variables fom a file of lines (test.dat) like

```
JAVA_HOME=c:\whereverjavahomeis
JAVA=c:\whereverjavais
```

then

```
@echo off
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (test.dat) do set %%I
)
```

is perfectly adequate. That's it - 4 lines (and it can all be condensed to 1 if you really try...)

The point is that you only need the `enabledelayedexpansion` and hence the `setlocal` in order to display the value of the variables you're changing `WITHIN THE LOOP WHERE YOU'RE CHANGING THE VALUES`. You'll eventually remove those lines, and the `enabledelayedexpansion` loses its *raison d'etre*.

For testing, you could write

```
@echo off
echo before...JAVA=%java%
echo before...JAVA_HOME=%java_home%
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (test.dat) do set %%I
)
echo after....JAVA=%java%
echo after....JAVA_HOME=%java_home%
```

or even

```
@echo off
echo before&set java
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (test.dat) do set %%I
)
echo after&set java
```

In fact, if `getVariables.bat` is only ever `CALL`ed then even the `@echo off` line is redundant - assuming you've executed `@echo off` from the calling batch.

Answer (score 0):

go into cmd and search setx. it lets you make system variables and all other kinds of things like even finding the x and y coordinates of a variable in a file.

Comment: How is it related to the question?