# Using local variables for a function which "returns" a result

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use local variables in a function but it doesn't work as expected.

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Sum %1, %2, sum
echo %sum%
exit /b 0

:Sum
setlocal
set "a=%~1"
set "b=%~2"
set /a "%~3=%a%+%b%"
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Here is the invocation of the script:

```
>test.bat 1 2
ECHO is off.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @montonero, the following *hack** solves the problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Sum %1 %2 sum
echo %sum%
exit /b 0

:Sum
setlocal
set "a=%~1"
set "b=%~2"
endlocal & (
    set /a "%~3=%a%+%b%"
)
exit /b 0
```

The command line `endlocal & ...` works due to the fact that variables are expanded before the command line is executed, thus creating a bridge between the local and the parent scope.

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291599/337149

Answer (score 2):

If the expected result is to put sum of arguments into a variable then you'll need to remove `setlocal`/`endlocal` inside of `:Sum`.

```
:Sum
set "a=%~1"
set "b=%~2"
set /a "%~3=%a%+%b%"
exit /b 0
```

Or you could try a trick from this answer [Batch script make setlocal variable accessed by other batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494688/batch-script-make-setlocal-variable-accessed-by-other-batch-files)

Also using of commas as argument delimiters for `call` isn't encouraged.

Comment: You're welcome. Though I wouldn't rely much on tricks since they aren't documented and not very reliable.

Comment: I agree in general but in this case it seems to be the only workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You get `ECHO is off.` because `%sum%` is not set. Here's an working example:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
CALL :Sum %1, %2, sum
ECHO %sum%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:Sum
SET /A "%~3 = %~1 + %~2"
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is a solution for the general case as described by the title of the question. My example was just an illustration; to add two command-line arguments I don't even need to define a function.